# How to retain lookup field value from the first time selection to second time

Tags: visualforce, javascript

[image]I have a InputTexField which has a custom lookup associated. Let's say I have associated three values A, B, C by opening lookup for First time. I have calling Javascript on the click of the OK which does A,B,C as association. Now I wanted to associate a different employee record so opened up the lookup second time and associated value say D. So in the inputText Field it should appear as A,B,C,D. My problem is that after opening second it erases the first time selection and it displays only D on click of 'Ok' button.

```
 <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <div align="Right" draggable="false">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Ok" id="selectEmp" onClick="selectAllEmployees();return false;"/>                        
                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="window.top.close()" />
            </div>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Calling Javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

function selectAllEmployees(){
    var selectedNames = [];
    var selectedIds   = [];
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input:checked'),
    function(v) {
         selectedNames.push(v.dataset.fullName);
         selectedIds.push(v.dataset.emailValue);
         alert(selectedNames);
         alert(selectedIds);
     });
     closeAndPassParams(selectedNames,selectedIds);
}

 function closeAndPassParams(nameTosend,idToSend){
   var parent = window.opener.document;
   var targetField = parent.getElementById('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.namefield}');
   var targetField1 = parent.getElementById('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.idfield}');
   targetField.value = nameTosend;
   targetField1.value = idToSend;
   self.close();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the new values with old values before assigning to the Parent fields. Check if any validation is required for the first time when `targetField` and `targetField1` are blank.

```
targetField.value = targetField.value + nameTosend;
targetField1.value = targetField1.value + idToSend;
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why my brain didn't think it to be simple rather over thinking :).

Comment: I need to append comma after every name so I modified your code as
 targetField.value = targetField.value + ',' + nameTosend;

 But the problem here is it always append , as the first value. Like ,test@example.com,test1@example.com. I tried to remove the comma by validating 
 targetField.Value in the if condition like If(targetField.value !== "undefined") but that didn't help. Any idea how would I remove that first comma?

Comment: I was able to do this by targetField.value = targetField.value.replace(/^,/, '');